# Zookeeper watch: under the hood?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am a freshman to Zookeeper who is trying to write a monitoring system to know when my servers are offline.

I use zkp_client running inside the servers and register themselves as ephemeral znodes, and then I set a watch in the monitor part to log this event.

Everything works well!

But I'm confused about the reacting speed: I found zookeeper use 2 seconds heartbeat to maintain the znodes, but it seems the watch can detect the ephemeral znode lost without any delay.

So the question is: how ephemeral znode trigger the watch event before it lose the connection? Is it trapping some system signal? Or, where can I find some tips from the source code?

Comment: Ephemeral Nodes are deleted if the client that created them crashes or looses connection to Zookeeper. The specifics of how this is done is what your asking, correct?

Comment: Yes. Especially why zookeeper react so fast in this case.

Comment: Zookeeper Source is out on GitHub. It's probably worth checking out and running a few experiments to get the details you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I will start from ephemeral node.

Comment: Good Luck. It would be great to see what you find out.